# Move items to a specified subfolder inside Outlook based on ReceivedTime

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-filter

I'm trying to move Outlook Items, However the code runs with no error messages but no emails are moved.

This leads me to belief the necessary `IF condition` is never being met? However I could be wrong.

Please find code below.

```
Sub Gatekeeper()
    Dim aItem As Object
    Dim mail As Object
    Dim strTime As String
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set mail = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = mail.Items

    For Each aItem In Items
        strTime = aItem.ReceivedTime

        If strTime > #6:00:00 PM# And strTime < #5:30:00 AM# Then
            Set subfolder = mail.Folders("Nights")
            aItem.Move subfolder
        End If

    Next aItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Place the cursor within the code and press "F8". This will take you through your code one step at a time, and you can check if the condition is met or not (either with some added `debug.print` or by hovering over variables with your cursor). Tell us afterwards if your `If` condition is being met or not.

Comment: Thank you David G for your helpful comment. The code does skip straight from IF to End IF. Is storing the receivedTime as a string correct? could that be causing when comparing it against the conditions in my IF?

Comment: Did you try the `If (DateDiff("d", myItem.SentOn, Now)) > 7
   'move mail
End If` from last post?

Comment: Hi David, 'If (DateDiff("d", myItem.SentOn, Now)) > 7 'move mail End If' does move mail however it doesn't do it based on time sent. I am interested in moving all between 6pm and 5.30am (filtering out night shift emails from day shift)

Comment: After the line `strTime = aItem.ReceivedTime` add the line `debug.print aItem.ReceivedTime` and post the output

Comment: 24/04/2017 08:52:33 
24/04/2017 08:43:30 
24/04/2017 08:33:31 
24/04/2017 08:30:39
and so on..

Answer (score 1):

*You shouldn't use **For Each...Next Loop** when you are  Moving /deleting or modifying collection Items*

> *<sub>Use a For Each...Next loop when you want to repeat a set of statements for each element of a collection or array.</sub>*
>
> ---

*Work with **For...Next Statement** - Down for loop:*

```
For i = Items.Count to 1 step -1

Next
```

> *<sub>A **[For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx#Syntax)** works well when you can associate each iteration of a loop with a control variable and determine that variable's initial and final values. However, when you are dealing with a collection, the concept of initial and final values isn't meaningful, and you don't necessarily know how many elements the collection has. In this kind of case, a **[For Each...Next loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)** is often a better choice.</sub>*
>
> ---

*Also remember there are **objects** other than **[MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx)** in your Inbox so check **[If Items.Class = olMail Then](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863329.aspx)** or you will encounter and error on your loop*

*You may also wanna use **[Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** to improve your loop*

> *<sub>**[Items.Restrict Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** Applies a filter to the Items collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter.
>
>   The method is an alternative to using the **[Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx)** or **[FindNext method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482.aspx)** to iterate over specific items within a collection. The **Find or FindNext methods** are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The Restrict method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.</sub>*
>   _
>
> ---

*Code Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim i As Long

    Filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
              CStr(Date - 1) & _
             " 06:00PM' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & _
              CStr(Date) & " 05:30AM'"

    Debug.Print Filter

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Debug.Print Items(i) ' Print on Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Item.Move Inbox.Folders("Nights")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Make sure to set your Filter correctly, I'm assuming your looking at yesterdays **`06:00PM`** **[CStr(Date - 1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch47ss2a.aspx) = (today - 1 day)**

***[CStr and Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch47ss2a.aspx)***

> *<sub>The Date type always contains both date and time information. For purposes of type conversion, Visual Basic considers 1/1/0001 (January 1 of the year 1) to be a neutral value for the date, and 00:00:00 (midnight) to be a neutral value for the time. CStr does not include neutral values in the resulting string. For example, if you convert #January 1, 0001 9:30:00# to a string, the result is "9:30:00 AM"; the date information is suppressed. However, the date information is still present in the original Date value and can be recovered with functions such as **[DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127415.aspx)**.</sub>*
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over all items in the folder you need to find items that correspond to your conditions and move them to a subfolder (or any other folder) by calling the Move method.

You need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class to find all items that correspond to your conditions (read and sender name). Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Then you can use the [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the MailItem class to move a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder. For example:

```
Sub MoveItems() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 
 Dim myItem As Object 
 Dim searchCriteria As String

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items 
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Personal Mail") 
 Set searchCriteria = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & CStr(Date - 1) & " 06:00PM' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & CStr(Date) & " 05:30AM'"
 Set myItem = myItems.Find(searchCriteria) 
 While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing" 
  myItem.Move myDestFolder 
  Set myItem = myItems.FindNext 
 Wend 
End Sub
```

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.