# How to apply filter on recent N Outlook.Items and get Outlook.Items after filtering?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-filter

I want to use the following code to filter out Unread outlook mails,but I want to apply this Restriction on recent N Outlook.Items.But I could not find any such method.

```
Outlook.Explorer currExplorer = null;
Outlook.Folder currFolder = null;
Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
Outlook.Items restrictedItems = null;
Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
Outlook.Attachments attachments = null;
int attachmentCount = 0;

try
{

    currExplorer = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
    currFolder = currExplorer.CurrentFolder as Outlook.Folder;
    if (currFolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    {
        folderItems = currFolder.Items;
        restrictedItems = folderItems.Restrict("[Unread]=true");


        for (int i = 1; i <= restrictedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            mail = restrictedItems[i] as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mail != null)
            {
                attachments = mail.Attachments;
                attachmentCount += attachments.Count;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachments);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622710/4539709

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Restrict` method twice - first for getting the recent N items and second for getting unread items between them. There is no query to get the N items in the collection, but you can use the time and time range for filtering items, see [Enumerating, Searching, and Filtering Items in a Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/enumerating-searching-and-filtering-items-in-a-folder)  for more information.

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Using Find and FindNext is known but it will be a performance hit. I will have to iterate to get N items if I use this approach, but what I'm looking for is some approach out of the box to get N items. I'm open to use any other library if that helps