# Replying to an Outlook mail based on subject, received time and date

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I will receive the Journal entries from the client and need to reply to the same mail.

I have tried the below code to execute reply to chain of mails. But the code is returning the all mails which contains the same subject line.

I need to reply which comes recently. I have tried many solutions, but I unable to fix it.

How do I Reply to an email based on subject, received time and date

```
Sub mail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail ' As Outlook.MailItem


Dim i As Integer

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFldr = Fldr
 For Each olMail In olFldr.Items

      If InStr(olMail.Subject, Range("C2")) <> 0 Then
        Set ReplyAll = olMail.ReplyAll
        With ReplyAll
            .HTMLBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
              "Hi Veronica <br><br>" & _
              "The " & _
               Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & "</B> has been posted.<br>" & _
               "<br><br>Regards," & _
              "<br><br>Rajesh</font>" & .HTMLBody

            emailReady = True
            .Display
        End With
    End If
Next olMail
If Not emailReady Then
i = i + 1
If i > Fldr.Folders.Count Then
    MsgBox ("The email with the given subject line was not found!")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set olFldr = Fldr.Folders(i)
    GoTo tryAgain
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Work with **[Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** to Filter by Subject and Date & Time*

*Make sure to convert your subject `Range("C2")` to [string variable then use it on your filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/filtering-items-using-a-variable)*

---

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Subject As String
        Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Text
        Debug.Print Subject

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                           Chr(34) & " >= '02/20/2018' And " & _
                           Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                           Chr(34) & " < '02/25/2018' And " & _
                           Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                           Chr(34) & "Like '%" & Subject & "%'"

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is mailitem Then
            Dim Item As Object
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Print on Immediate Window
            Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime ' Print on Immediate Window
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

> *<sub>[Items.Restrict Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Applies a filter to the [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863652.aspx) collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter.</sub>*
>
> ---

***Edit - Complete Code***

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Subject As String
        Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Text
        Debug.Print Subject

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                           Chr(34) & " >= '03/07/2018' And " & _
                           Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                           Chr(34) & " < '03/25/2018' And " & _
                           Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                           Chr(34) & "Like '%" & Subject & "%'"

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Dim Item As Object
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Print on Immediate Window
            Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime ' Print on Immediate Window

            Dim ReplyAll As Outlook.MailItem
            Set ReplyAll = Item.ReplyAll

            With ReplyAll
                .HTMLBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
                  "Hi Veronica <br><br>" & _
                  "The " & Left(ActiveWorkbook.name, _
                          InStr(ActiveWorkbook.name, ".") - 1) & _
                  "</B> has been posted.<br>" & _
                  "<br><br>Regards," & _
                  "<br><br>Rajesh</font>" & .HTMLBody

                .Display
            End With

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622710/4539709*