# Download the attachment only from the from latest outlook email using Python?

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, pywin32, office-automation

I am trying to download and save the outlook email attachment from the most recent email in a folder.

I have a code that downloads all of the attachment from a outlook folder and saves it.

Any help is appreciated.

```
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client

output_dir = Path.home()/r"Documents\Test"
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders("Sample Folder").folders("Sample Subfolder")
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()

for message in messages:
    if message.Subject == 'Sample Subject' or message.Subject == 'Sample Subject 2':
        attachments = message.Attachments
        subject = messages.GetFirst().Subject

        for attachment in attachments:
            attachment.SaveAsFile(output_dir / str(attachment))
```

Comment: Can you tell us what isn't working? Is there an error or unexpected output?

Comment: So this code works perfectly to download all of the attachment from a given folder.
But I want to download attachment from the most recent email in the folder.

Comment: most recent? add filter by date range - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49204941/4539709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to download and save the outlook email attachment from the most recent email in a folder.

To get the most recent item from the folder you need to sort the collection first by using the Sort method in the following way (VBA):

```vb
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[RecievedTime]", false) 
message = messages.GetFirst()
```

Also iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
for message in messages:
    if message.Subject == 'Sample Subject' or message.Subject == 'Sample Subject 2':
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class. They allows getting items that correspond to your conditions without iterating over all items in the folder. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thank you @Eugene Astafiev for the solution and assisting me in my journey to learn python, I will look into your articles :)

Comment: Python is not related to that, that is purely the Outlook object model question.