# Loop thought my Outlook inbox using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

Hi I want to retrieve all the email from 2017-06-29 to today but I only get save in MS access from Today to July 31 2018 which represent about the last 23 days. I have over **7345 emails** on that inbox.

My error is that the loop stop after just over the 350th email

```
Sub log_your_inbox_to_ms_access()

    'our Outlook folder- deifinitions
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim myNamespace As NameSpace
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'put your folders name here
    'second is possibly 'inbox folder'
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders("GiftCard").Folders("Inbox")

    ' Set up DAO objects (uses existing Access "Email" table).
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Email")

    'Set Up Outlook objects.
    Dim cMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim cAtch As Outlook.Attachments


    Set myMail = myFolder.Items
    'MsgBox myMail.Count '7345

    Set objProp = myMail

    iNumMessages = objProp.Count
    If iNumMessages <> 0 Then
        For i = 5 To iNumMessages
            If TypeName(objProp(i)) = "MailItem" Then
                Set cMail = objProp(i)
                Debug.Print cMail.SentOn
                If (CDate(cMail.SentOn) > CDate("2017-06-29") And CDate(cMail.SentOn) < CDate("2018-08-22")) Then
                    rst.AddNew
                    rst!SenderName = cMail.SenderName
                    rst!Sender = cMail.SenderEmailAddress
                    rst!SentOn = cMail.SentOn
                    rst!To = cMail.To
                    rst!CC = cMail.CC
                    rst!Subject = cMail.Subject
                    rst.Update
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If



End Sub
```

When I debug 'i' it seems like it only contains 351 items

Comment: Try using `ReceivedTime` filter - Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622710/4539709

Comment: Appears  Access code is not needed. If so, edit the question to remove. [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There are no apparent errors in your code. So you already know how to loop through a folder.

After dropping the references to Access and extra variables you should find this code is essentially the same but simpler. Try to identify whether the problem is due to the GiftCard mailbox, Access ...

```
Sub log_folder_SimplerExample()

    Dim myNamespace As Namespace
    Dim myFolder As Folder

    Dim myMail As Items
    Dim cMail As mailItem

    Dim iNumMessages As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set myNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'put your folders name here
    'Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders("GiftCard").Folders("Inbox")
    'Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders("GiftCard").Folders("Sent Items")
    'Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders("GiftCard").Folders("Deleted Items")

    ' Check other folders for comparison
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    'Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)

    Set myMail = myFolder.Items

    MsgBox myMail.count

    ' Use myMail.count since the result is the expected
    ' Drop possibly extraneous variables

    iNumMessages = myMail.count

    If iNumMessages > 4 Then

        For i = 5 To iNumMessages

            If TypeName(myMail(i)) = "MailItem" Then

                Set cMail = myMail(i)

                Debug.Print i & " - " & myMail(i).SentOn

                If (CDate(cMail.SentOn) > CDate("2017-06-29") And CDate(cMail.SentOn) < CDate("2018-08-22")) Then
                    Debug.Print "   " & cMail.senderName & vbCr
                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End If

    Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```