# Script producing different results when moving inbox item to folder

Tags: vba, outlook

So my script tests perfectly but not when I comment out the actual 'move to folder' part. It only move half of the inbox items, if I run the script again it moves the half of the remaining inbox items.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Thanks

```
If InboxItem.ReceivedTime < myDate Then ' This sub checks for OLD emails OUTER LOOP  
            
        For x = 0 To UBound(lookUp)
                
           myCheck = InStr(1, InboxItem.SenderEmailAddress, lookUp(x), vbTextCompare) 'checks the lookup value
           
             
                If myCheck = True Then 'checks for text match
                    Debug.Print ("good to move " & InboxItem.SenderEmailAddress & " to " & lookUp(x) & " Folder: " & myFolder(x))  ' & " Subfolder")
                    
                    'InboxItem.Move myInbox.Folders("VBAtest").Folders(myFolder(x)) '<<< move to folder

                    Debug.Print "MOVED >>> " & InboxItem.Subject
                    
                   itemsMoved = itemsMoved + 1
                End If
        Next x

    End If
```

Expected to move all items as that's what happens when I use the `Debug.Print` to test

Comment: try moving items in reverse order https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622710/4539709